# SAS padded spaces

Tags: sas, string-length, pad

I have a data set that I have created and it needs to be formatted to have trailing/padded spaces to the specified number of characters.

Below are the field names from the STG data set.

```
'Social Security Number (SSN)'n
'Date of Birth'n 
'Last Name'n 
'First Name'n
```

SSN must start at position 1 and only be 9 characters long (position 1-9)

DOB must start at position 10 and be 8 characters long (position 10-17)

Last Name must start at position 18 and be 26 characters long (position 18-43)

First Name must start at pisition 44 and be 20 characters long (position 44-63)

so on and so forth.

When exported, I need to be able to see the padded/trailing spaces stored in the string. All my fields are formatted as character.

What is the best way to approach this? I've tried specify length and subpad in a data step but when exported, the trailing spaces are lost.

Comment: What are you creating? A text file?

Comment: Yes, it would be a text file. It needs to be uploaded to a site which requires the format to be as such.

Comment: Show example input data and expected output file format.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty trivial to generate a fixed column text file. Just use the PUT statement.

You can force fixed length lines by writing a space into the last column before writing the actual values.  That will insure that all lines are padded to at least that length.

```
 data _null_;
    file 'mydata.txt'  ;
    set have;
    put @63 ' '
      @ 1 SSN $9.
      @10 DOB yymmdd8.
      @18 LAST_NAME $26.
      @44 FIRST_NAME $20.
    ;
 run;
```

Comment: Thank you Tom. As stated previously, it needs to be uploaded to a site which requires the format to be as such.

I tried the above and added the additional fields I needed, however I am receiving an error.

ERROR 23-2: Invalid option name RECMF.

Thoughts?

Comment: Just fix my typo and the code should work.  Note you probably do not to include RECFM= option if you are explicitly writing using formats to fill every column.

Comment: Thank you. I think I'm almost there. I was expecting to see each record on a separate row, however they seem to run on one record after another when opened in a text editor. Meaning the second record isn't on a new line, it starts right after the first. Is there a way to start each record on a separate line? Not a big deal. Just something aesthetic the end user is asking for.

Comment: I would remove RECFM=F option.  Let me update the answer with a different method to insure all lines are same length.

Comment: Thank you Tom. I've changed the code to your updated statement however there is now a . showing at the very end of each record. The records are also still not on a separate row as expected.

Comment: A SAS statement starts with a keyword (such as `PUT`) and ends with a semi-colon.  @Tom broke the statement into four lines of source code for easy reading.  To have each field on a separate row (weird ?) you can add the line advance put directive (`/`) to the source code before the 2nd, 3rd and 4th `@` signs.  I think `$CHAR20.` will force trailing spaces in last field

Comment: One way the records would be merged would be because of leaving a trailing @ on the PUT statement. That will stop SAS from writing the end of line. Another way they could appear merged is if SAS wrote the files using LF as the end-of-line marker and the editor you are using is looking for CR+LF as the end of line marker.  You could try adding TERMSTR=CRLF to the FILE statement.  Extra dots will be caused by printing a variable with a missing value. Probably a typo like a misspelled name, leaving the period off of the format specification so it looks like another variable.

Comment: Adding TERMSTR=crlf to my file statement gave me a return as expected. Thank you for your assistance!